# Jquery Mobile changepage confusion

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In the example below, page1 receives new list items the first time it is loaded.  When you navigate to page2 and fire the changepage through script, the page does not receive the new list elements.

example code:

```
$('#page2').live('pageinit', function(event) {
  $.mobile.changePage( "page1.html", {reloadPage: true});
}

$('#page1').live('pageinit', function(event) {
  // insert new list items here
  $('#mylist').listview('refresh');
}
```

However, if you do the exact same thing, but alert something before hand, like so:

```
$('#page2').live('pageinit', function(event) {
  $.mobile.changePage( "page1.html", {reloadPage: true});
}

$('#page1').live('pageinit', function(event) {
  alert("testing...");
  // insert new list items here
  $('#mylist').listview('refresh');
}
```

The page does receive the new list items.  It's like it gets fired in a different sequence when being reloaded by changepage.  It must fire too quickly.  What function should I be using in order to wait?

Comment: Hum... The selector `#page2` will allow `page1.html` to change but at the same time your have `reloadPage:true` which seems like recursion will occur.

Answer (score 0):

Try `data-ajax="false"` on the link which direct to next page...

For Example,

```
<a href="page2.html" data-role="button" data-ajax="false"> Click</a>
```